# In SQL, how to query for rows based on the values in other rows at a certain relative position in the table

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

I have a database containing events which have a "time" (an integer) plus some other attributes.

E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE events (time, attr1, attr2);
INSERT INTO events VALUES (1, 'a', 'foo');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (2, 'b', 'bar');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (4, 'a', 'baz');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (9, 'b', 'quux');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (10, 'c', 'foobar');
```

Now I want to do a somewhat complicated query: I want to find all events which have the property that the *next* event in the table satisfies some condition. For instance, I might want to find all events that satisfy all these conditions:

- attr1 == 'a'
- the next event (as determined by the time field) has attr2 == 'bar'

This should return the event at time 1, but not the event at time 4. Or a more complicated example would be: find all events that satisfy

- attr1 == 'a'
- the next event *for which attr1 == 'c'* has attr2 == 'foobar'

This would return both the events at times 1 and 4.

It seems like this ought to be possible via some sort of complicated nested select, but I haven't managed to work out how.

Other notes:

- I'm using sqlite.
- Events are irregularly spaced, so strategies that involve computing the position of the 'next' event won't work.
- I know these queries are going to be murder on the query optimizer, that's okay.
- I know how to do this by doing multiple selects + non-SQL logic, but I'd much rather do it using pure SQL, because this is embedded in a larger query generation system. I need to be able to generate queries of this form in general, conjoined with other constraints, etc., it's not just a single query I'll write once and be done with.

Comment: There is no time 3. Please note that the event at time 1 also matches your second query because there is a later `c` event.

Comment: @CL: Thanks, edited to correct both points.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a record that is the next after some specific time by combining `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE time > 1
ORDER BY time
LIMIT 1
```

By using this in a subquery, you can look up values from the *next* record.

Your first query can be implemented like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM events AS e2
WHERE attr1 = 'a'
  AND (SELECT attr2
       FROM events
       WHERE time > e2.time
       ORDER BY time
       LIMIT 1) = 'bar'
```

Your second query can be implemented like this (the additional condition belongs into the `WHERE` of the subquery):

```
SELECT *
FROM events AS e2
WHERE attr1 = 'a'
  AND (SELECT attr2
       FROM events
       WHERE attr1 = 'c'
         AND time > e2.time
       ORDER BY time
       LIMIT 1) = 'foobar'
```

The subquery lookups can be made faster with an index on the `time` column.

Comment: Second query will fail if exist a `9, 'c', '~foobar'`.

Comment: @LS_dev What do you mean with "fail"? With that record, it will not return any records, because there is none that satifies the condition.

Comment: If you have 2 'c' (after `e2.time`), first != 'foobar' and second = 'foobar', second will be choice, but your query return nothing.

Comment: @LS_dev The question does not ask for *any* record with 'c' and 'foobar', it asks whether the next 'c' record has 'foobar' or not.

Comment: Not explicit: immediate next, or any of following? Your code doesn't choose immediate, choose following with 'c'. Why not following with 'c' and 'foobar'? But our discussion is becoming pointless as should OP being the one to clarify this point!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from events a
where exists 
  (
   select * from events c where c.time =
  (select min(b.time) from events b where b.time > a.time)--next_event
   and c.attr2 = 'bar'
  )
and a.attr1 = 'a'
```

should be your first query. It returns time 1.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63baf/12

the second could be :

```
select * from events a
where exists 
  (
   select * from events c where c.time =
  (select min(b.time) from events b where b.time > a.time and attr1 = 'c')
   and c.attr2 = 'foobar'
  )
and a.attr1 = 'a'
```

but it returns time 1 and 4 (unlike what you expect, but both these rows comply with your conditions)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63baf/15

hope this helps

Nicolas